# Use the Same Excel VB Code In Multiple Workbooks Used by Multiple Users Without Having to Update Each Workbook

Tags: excel, xlsm

### tl;dr: Is there a way to have multiple (10+) excel Macro workbooks run the same project from a single location so that if I need to fix a bug, I don't need to fix it in every single workbook?

Long version:

My company uses excel workbooks for engineering charts. Any changes are formatted as bold and highlighted gray. We then have a revision "table" at the bottom (I say "table" because it's just some merged cells - there doesn't seem to be a way to make a separate table that doesn't follow the column sizing for the rest of the workbook, but that's a question for another day).

When we do a new revision, we have to first clear any formatting from the previous revision, make our changes (and format them), then insert a row to the revision "table", then unformat the previous revision entry and reformat our new revision entry. Then, we export the workbook as a PDF which we name according to our print naming format. However, it is easy to make mistakes when doing this because the file name must be manually entered according to the format.

To make this process less tedious/error-prone, I wrote a VB macro program to automate the above steps, among other things. It works great, and will be implemented on our charts company wide.

However, I can only do so much testing on my own - there are bound to be things I missed or can do more efficiently (I'm an engineer, not a professional programmer). And we have dozens of engineering chart spreadsheets. If we implement this and then I discover I need to fix a bug or make an improvement to part of the program, I don't want to have to fix it in every single workbook - that would take way too long and be too easy to miss a workbook!

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look into XLAM files

Comment: 1. How are you detecting changes? 2. Is there a central location you could store the code that would serve as a single "source of truth"? 3. Could you turn this around a little -- have a separate workbook that would ask for a source file and destination folder, and generate a new transformed file from the source file?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I am trying this now, however I am having trouble finding good resources on how to write XLAM's.

Here's the latest: I am looking into using a template file to create the new charts. The template is used to make sure the format required by the XLAM is followed

Inside the template file I put the XLAM. It has a form with a bunch of buttons for the various automation tools. Here are my questions: 
1.  How do I get this form to load on workbook open?
2. How does the add in know which workbook/sheet to modify?